# Laravel | Удаление элемента коллекции

Tags: php, laravel, коллекции

Мы получаем все элементы коллекции из бд:
$test = Goods::all();
Прогоняем по циклу и получаем какой-то элемент. Необходимо из коллекции $test удалить его.
Как это сделать?
Полный код если надо:

```
    $searchQuery = $request->validated()['search'];
    $test = Goods::all();
    $checkHandler = new Search;
    foreach ($test as $t) {
        if (!$checkHandler->Search($searchQuery, $t)) {
            // Тут необходимо удалять из $test эллемент $t когда Метод Search возвращает false
        }
    }
```

PS: её богу, такой элементарный вопрос, но спустя больше часа копошения в документации и в гугле получил только нервный срыв. Уточню что id поста не всегда равно номеру итерации foreach

Comment: а нельзя сразу выбрать коллекцию с условием? сэкономишь время отклика и ресурсы

Comment: @sterx Пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: where метод или whereIn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    foreach ($test as $key => $t) {
    if (!$checkHandler->Search($searchQuery, $t)) {
        unset($test[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: или forget метод
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-forget